# C# Casting implementation of (interface with generic argument that is also an interface) results to InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, casting

i am trying to create a dictionary of handlers for all classes that implement IAnimal, but i am unable to properly cast the concrete handler class to the IAnimalHandler interface, what is wrong with this code? should i setup inheritance differently?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

var handlerMap = new Dictionary<Type, IAnimalHandler<IAnimal>>();

AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.Name.Contains(nameof(IAnimalHandler<IAnimal>))))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(t => 
             {
                 var animalType = t.GetInterfaces()
                     .First(i => i.Name.Contains(nameof(IAnimalHandler<IAnimal>)))
                     .GetGenericArguments()[0];

                 var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

                 handlerMap[animalType] = (IAnimalHandler<IAnimal>) instance;
             });

public interface IAnimal {}

public class Dog : IAnimal {}

public interface IAnimalHandler<IAnimal> {}

public class DogHandler : IAnimalHandler<Dog> {}
```

the exception message

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of 
  type 'DogHandler' to type 'IAnimalHandler`1[IAnimal]'.
```

dotnetfeedle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/adfNL9

Comment: Can you share the actual error message you are receiving?

Comment: @Jasen just did, also added a dotnetfeedle link

Answer (score 1):

First in your declaration

```
IAnimalHandler<IAnimal>
```

IAnimal it's the name for a generic type parameter, not the reference to the IAnimal interface. It's confusing. Just redefine in the following way:

```
public interface IAnimalHandler<out T> where T : IAnimal { }
```

**out** modifier is required to be able to perform an assignment operation:

```
IAnimalHandler<Dog> -> IAnimalHandler<IAnimal>
```

Read the following article if you would like to know more about covariance in c#:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Answer (score 1):

The casting is not working because `IAnimalHandler<Dog>` cannot be stored in `IAnimalHandler<IAnimal>`. Let's see an example.

```cs
IAnimal dog = new Dog();

// Not working
IAnimalHandler<IAnimal> handler = new DogHandler();

public interface IAnimal { }

public class Dog : IAnimal { }
public class Cat : IAnimal { }


public interface IAnimalHandler<T> where T : IAnimal {
    public void Handle(T animal);
}

public class DogHandler : IAnimalHandler<Dog>
{
    public void Handle(Dog animal)
    {
        // Handle logic here...
    }
}

public class CatHandler : IAnimalHandler<Cat>
{
    public void Handle(Cat animal)
    {
        // Handle logic here...
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's not possible to assign `DogHandler` to the variable `handler`. A variable of type `IAnimalHandler<IAnimal>` means that the concrete underlying class should have a method with this signature `public void Handle(IAnimal animal)`. This method would accept any type that implements `IAnimal`. The type `DogHandler` only accepts Dog in it's Handle method which is not any `IAnimal` implementation.

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do with this, but here's an example that could satisfy your needs

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

var handlerMap = new Dictionary<Type, IAnimalHandler>();

AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.Name.Contains(nameof(IAnimalHandler))))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(t =>
    {
        IAnimalHandler instance = (IAnimalHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        handlerMap[instance.HandledType] = instance;
    });

handlerMap[typeof(Dog)].Handle(new Dog());

public interface IAnimal { }

public class Dog : IAnimal { }
public class Cat : IAnimal { }


public interface IAnimalHandler
{
    Type HandledType { get; }
    public void Handle(IAnimal animal);
}

public class DogHandler : IAnimalHandler
{
    public Type HandledType => typeof(Dog);

    public void Handle(IAnimal animal)
    {
        if (animal is Dog dog)
        {
            // Handle dog here...
            Console.WriteLine("Dog handled");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException($"Expected to handle a {typeof(Dog)} got {animal.GetType()}");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helped you!